# retrieving more than 1000 rows from table storage using python

Tags: python, azure-storage

I am using the following pattern from this forum to pull data from table storage:

```
next_pk=0
next_rk=0
while True:
    xa=table_service.query_entities(table_name=tableName, filter=dataFilter, num_results=1000, next_partition_key = next_pk, next_row_key = next_rk )
    i+=1
    if hasattr(accelxa, 'x_ms_continuation'):
        x_ms_continuation = getattr(accelxa, 'x_ms_continuation')
        next_pk = x_ms_continuation['nextpartitionkey']
        next_rk = x_ms_continuation['nextrowkey']
    else:
        break;
```

But when I run it I get the following exception:

```
TypeError was unhandled by user code
Message: query_entities() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_partition_key'
```

So it would appear the api has changed from when the example was written and I am unable to determine what the new api is.

I have looked at github and there is reference to a marker object in the method call but I am unclear how to use it. Any example would be helpful.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py

```
 def _query_entities(self, table_name, filter=None, select=None, max_results=None, marker=None, accept=TablePayloadFormat.JSON_MINIMAL_METADATA, property_resolver=None, timeout=None, _context=None):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Github code:

```
def _query_entities(self, table_name, filter=None, select=None, max_results=None,
                   marker=None, accept=TablePayloadFormat.JSON_MINIMAL_METADATA,
                   property_resolver=None, timeout=None, _context=None):
        ...

        next_partition_key = None if marker is None else marker.get('nextpartitionkey')
```

From this syntax, you have to initialize `marker` keyword argument as a dictionaty (`dict`) and set `marker['nextpartitionkey']` (not `'next_partition_key'`) equal to value you want.

```
xa = table_service.query_entities(..., marker={'nextpartitionkey'= ...}, ...)
```

Also you should remove `next_row_key` keyword argument from your code and initialize `marker['nextrowkey']` the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue successfully, then I discovered the issue was caused by the `query_entities` method in your code which was incompatible with the `azure-storage` package version you installed.

According to the source code from GitHub, you can find the version difference as below.

In the version `v0.20.x`, for example, the latest version `v0.20.3`, [the method `query_entities` definition](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/v0.20.3/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py#L385) as below, it has the arguments `next_partition_key` & `next_row_key`.

> ```
> def query_entities(self, table_name, filter=None, select=None, top=None, 
>                    next_partition_key=None, next_row_key=None):
> ```

But after `v0.20.3`, [the method definition (for example `v0.33.0`)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/v0.33.0/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py#L664) changed as @DmitryFrolov said, as below.

> ```
> def query_entities(self, table_name, filter=None, select=None, num_results=None,
>                    marker=None, accept=TablePayloadFormat.JSON_MINIMAL_METADATA,
>                    property_resolver=None, timeout=None):
> ```

So there are two solutions for resolving the issue.

1. Rollback the package version via commands `pip uninstall azure-storage` & `pip install azure-storage==0.20.3`, then your code will works fine.
2. Under your current version, as @DmitryFrolov said, construct a `marker` object to include the parameters `next_partition_key` & `next_row_key` for following the new usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using azure-storage **0.34.3**, I was able use the following code:

```
table_service = TableService(account_name, account_key)
i=0
marker = None
while True:
    tasks = table_service.query_entities(table_name, data_filter,
                                         marker = marker,
                                         num_results=1000)
    for task in tasks:
      i += 1
      print(task)
    if tasks.next_marker is not None and len(tasks.next_marker) > 0:
      marker = tasks.next_marker
    else:
        break


print i
```

Note that you no longer need to construct your own marker object.  Just use the one passed back to you, and check that the marker dictionary actually has some content; the marker dictionary should have two items if there are more rows to process.